# Async call issue with google actions appeared out of nowhere

Tags: actions-on-google

I had an action published and working fine . I made no changes to the code.

Suddenly it gives an error saying this:

> Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?

This is the problematic area of the code, I updated fetch and still nothing works.

Updated fetch, now showing "fetch": "^1.1.0", in package.json

```
return fetch("https://xxx-xxx.xxx/jsonfile.json").then(function(response){
  console.log("this step");      
  return response.json(); // process it inside the `then`
});

if (!conv.user.storage.visited && !conv.user.storage.randmozier) {
  console.log("372");


  currentquestion = response[questionnumber].n111.toString();


  const ssml =
    '<speak>' +
    currentquestion +
    '</speak>';
  conv.ask(ssml);

}
```

How could this suddenly stop working?
In the code it also goes to a randomizer function that determines questionnumber.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how are you calling this code from inside your Intent Handler? I don't think the problem is specifically here, but in how it is called (or how you handle the Promise from this when it is returned).

Comment: I've added more to the code, it just processes the response and pulls questions from it.  I still don't see how this could just stop working on its own, it worked fine for 2 weeks with over 1500 players and suddenly this issue -- how could it be the code?

Based on the console.log errors I know it stops right at the return fetch part above.  

More confusion: Google is crawling my app and it is showing console.log messages from an unpublished draft version -- how can their crawler see my draft version to see if this latest release is healthy?  I think this is a problem w/ Google.

Comment: Your code, as you've shown it, doesn't make sense. If you're returning before your `if` statement, that statement would never get called.

Comment: Yeah that's true this was an error in showing the abbreviated version of the code.  I appreciate all your help now and in the past, but google has already emailed me saying it was their error as their crawler was testing my draft version which did indeed have a typo in it.  A draft version being crawled and causing my published version to get disabled.